# errors after copy of .mm extension files from another project

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

i have copied .mm files from old project to my new project , after copied i am facing errors in each .h file of that class

Unknown type name 'class': did you mean 'Class'?
Expected';' after top level declarator

Comment: Do you use Objective C++ code in that .mm files?